# How to set position and dimension of DIVs nested inside a DIV wrapper?

Tags: html, nested, wrapper

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-div"> [Content] </div>
    <div id="top-right-div"> [Content] </div>
    <div id="bottom-right-div"> [Content] </div>
</div>
```

**left-div** has greater height than **top-right-div** and **bottom-right-div** together. I would like the **left-div** to be always on the left side of the wrapper, **top-right-div** at the top right and **bottom-right-div** at the bottom right.

Is it also possible for the wrapper to adjust its size depending on all the inner `<div>s` height and width?

I tried by setting *absolute, float, display and overflow* but I cannot get to the desired result. Thanks in advance

UPDATE

jsfiddle use case: http://jsfiddle.net/sBSfp/

Comment: In my understanding HTML and Co. are not really keen to do this kind of stuff. For the last part of your question, you can set the size of a div based on its content using `display: table` style.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a use case on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Paolo: thanks, I created a jsfiddle use case. where I set height and width of the wrapper if, I take them out it will shrink. You can find it at: http://jsfiddle.net/sBSfp/

Answer (score 0):

I updated the fiddle to implement what I understnd you want to do

http://jsfiddle.net/sBSfp/2/

If it is not the desired layout please further describe it.